# Battery efficient GPS/Sat Nav app

Tags: iphone, battery, gps

I'm looking for a battery efficient satellite navigation app for use on my bike. The problem is that GPS apps are a huge drain on the battery. My iPhone 6S lasts just under 3 hours when running Google Maps.

Years ago, I remember some app that had the feature of dimming the screen in between navigation instructions. I've checked Apple Maps, Google Maps and Waze and these do not appear to have the feature I describe.

Does anyone know of a good GPS/Sat Nav app that is gentle on the battery?

Comment: I use my 6 for bike rides, running, and car drives (without plugging it in) for longer than 3 hours. You shouldn't need to look at your screen all the time, and thus keep your screen bright and killing the battery.  Are you using it with the screen on all the time for your rides?

Comment: @fsb Yes the screen is on. Do you mean that you turn your screen off and just listen to the instructions? Or will the screen turn back on when the next instruction is close? The latter is what I'd like to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I took in the end involves turning off the screen when riding on my bike. The audio navigation instructions still come through on my Bluetooth earpiece, and the instructions are accurate even if my phone is in my pocket.

Now I get to ride without anything cluttering up my handlebars, and my phone lasts long enough for the journeys I make.